# How can I run native code (in a DLL) from UnrealScript in UT/UE1?

Tags: unreal

I'm seeking an example showing how to create a DLL that can be called from UnrealScript in Unreal Engine 1 or Unreal Tournament.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Epic seems to have removed most of the documentation for non-UDK versions of the engine from public view.

[Archive.org preserved some documentation from how to do it within UE2](http://web.archive.org/web/20080822135510/http://udn.epicgames.com/Two/NativeFunctions.html) (which is probably closer to UE1 than UE3), but I can't turn up anything official for UE1 anywhere.

[UnrealWiki has a Legacy Native Coding page](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:Native_Coding), but many of the links on it are now dead.

Writing native code in many versions of Unreal, as well as writing Native Classes in UE3, requires a source license.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UDN](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DLLBind.html), that function was added to Unreal Engine 3 on December 2009's version, and wasn't made available for older builds. Looks like you're out of luck.

Comment: DLLBind is what UDK uses to bind native code to UnrealScript dynamically; as the page notes, people with access to real UE3 use Native Classes, and the question is about UE1, not UE3 or UDK.